# Find Google Chrome installation directory using Terminal

Tags: macos, applications, command-line

How do I find the Google Chrome Installation Directory/Path using the command line?
Is Google Chrome always installed to the default path, the "/Applications/" folder?

I have tried the following commands. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

1. `locate "*Chrome.app"`

   When i used this command it only search the DB entries of installed software.
2. `find / -type d -name "*Chrome.app"`

   Lists all the files on the system.

How can I find only Google Chrome’s path using this command, or is there another way?

Comment: As noted the find command should work a better version would be to not include the * - what does it actually show ?

Comment: why do you need this path?

Answer (score 22):

You can query for this kind of information using the Launch Services database to dump a list of all registered apps, then `grep` for the one you want (in this case Google Chrome), for example (using Mountain Lion 10.8.4):

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump | grep -i "google chrome"
```

gives me the output:

```
path:          /Applications/Google Chrome.app/
executable:    Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
path:          /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/27.0.1453.116/Google Chrome Helper.app/
executable:    Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Helper
```

Comment: Executable path is the same on our Mac OS 10.13.3 (/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)

Answer (score 9):

You could do this from a shell prompt:

```
osascript -e 'POSIX path of (path to application "Chrome")'
```

However note that this will also launch Chrome if it isn't already running.

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860517/path-to-application-without-opening-it

Answer (score 4):

Your second command

```
find / -type d -name "*Chrome.app"
```

should work - it works ok on my system.

What do you mean by "List all the file on system"? "find" will search your file system from '/' as you specified, but if you think Chrome.app could get installed in some odd place, "find" is one sure way to locate it.

Comment: Hi Keith,
Thanks for reply. I needs to find the absolute path of the application (Google Chrome) only using terminal, that command i will used in my MDM Zinc Application.My Project Requirement

Comment: If you mean "find all installations of Chrome" on your file system, 'find' as you've written will provide those paths.

Answer (score 0):

To find all Google Chrome paths use:

```
find / -name '*Chrome.app' 2>1
```